# PowerPoint 2011 Mac Narration

Tags: powerpoint, osx-yosemite

I made a PowerPoint presentation with PP 2011 for Mac, and went through and narrated it. After narration, I could go through the entire presentation and hear my voice. I saved the file and closed it. When I opened it later, there was still the narration icon under each slide, but no sound. I have replicated this issue with other presentations. Narrations record and work fine, until you close the file and open it again. How do I save the sound? I ran a search for any .wav files and found nothing in my entire user directory. Narration timings also seem to work correctly, just no audio.

Comment: Could you accept your answer, please?  And thank you for posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being that the file was being saved as a ppt, not a pptx. So powerpoint would allow you to record a narration but it wouldn't save the audio.